# Connection of RYU controller and Flowvisor

Tags: mininet, sdn, pox, ryu

I am using RYU and POX controller with Flowvisor over Mininet. When I connect POX controller to flowvisor (the ports of my slices are 10000 and 20000), I use this line:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/pox && ./pox.py openflow.of_01 --port=10000 forwarding.<name_of_controller>
```

What about RYU controller connection? What is the line to connect RYU controller to a specific port (except 6633) of flowvisor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder where you installed `Ryu`, and then:

```
$ cd ryu
$ PYTHONPATH=. ./bin/ryu-manager ryu/app/simple_switch.py --ofp-tcp-listen-port 20000
```

Instead of `simple_switch.py` you can use the other models that are in the folder `ryu/app/`!